# Working with Hibernate relationships

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm working in Hibernate. I got 3 entities, that's the relationship among them:

User 1 -> N Orders 1 -> N Order Details

how could I add a row in table "Order details" of a specific Order for a given User?

I know how to add a new row in table Orders and Order Details, something like that:

```
User user=(User)session.get(User.class, username);
Order order=new Order();
OrderDetails orderDetails=new OrderDetails();
orderDetails.setAmount(1);
order.addOrderDetails(orderDetails);
user.addOrder(order);
session.save(user); 
transaction.commit();
```

It is correct?

But what happen when I only want to add a row in table addOrderDetails of a specific Order for a given User? Could i do this?

```
List<Order> o=session.createCriteria(Order.class) 
.add( Restrictions.eq("idUser", User) );
o.get(0).addOrderDetails(orderDetails);
```

Actually i don't know how to work with tables Orders and Orders details, should i do from User table? How? Using Criteria from User table i only can get a list of users, but can not work with the others tables.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have mapping that represents your relationship, you can get User and user would have a set or list with elements of type Order. Then you can update the specific order.

Methods that you have described are also correct short of some mistakes (call `list()` on criteria to get list for example).

Answer (score 0):

It seems a user may own a lot of resources, if you access orders from the User object, it may impact on the performance.

```
// user.addOrder(order);
// session.save(user); 
order.setUser(user);
session.save(order);
```

Also remove the orders property from the User class would clean up the design. But again it depends on the business model.